# Vue 3 Array state change doesn't trigger watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a table with a checkbox for each row and a head checkbox which selects all of them, when any checkbox state is changed, it should trigger an event but for some reason when i use the main checkbox to check them all, the watcher doesn't get triggered until i unchecked it:

template:

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <input
     type="checkbox"
     class="form-check-input widget-9-check"
     :name="name"
     v-model="areAllItemsSelected"
    />
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr v-for="..."> //here is rowIndex
   <td>
    <input
     type="checkbox"
     class="form-check-input widget-9-check"
     :value="rowIndex"
     v-model="selectedItems"
    />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

setup:

```js
setup(props, {emit}) {
    const selectedItems = ref([])
    const areAllItemsSelected = ref(false)

    watch(areAllItemsSelected, (newValue) => {
      if(newValue) {
        items.value.forEach((item, index) => {
          selectedItems.value.push(index) //this should trigger the below watcher
        })
      } else {
        selectedItems.value = []
      }

    })

    watch(selectedItems, (newValue) => { //this doesn't run when areAllItemsSelected is checked, only when is unchecked
      emit('itemSelected', newValue)
    })

    return {
      items,
      selectedItems,
      areAllItemsSelected
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vue 3 requires the [`deep` watcher flag when watching arrays](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/watch.html). Pass the `deep` flag in the third argument of `watch()`:

```js
watch(selectedItems, (newValue) => {/*...*/}, { deep: true })
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-watch-array-changes?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: It does indeed! Thank you Tony. I wonder why is this not referenced in the documentation, rather it is falsely stated that watching reactive objects is deep by default...